# ToDo list example: error adding task (setOnKeyListener)

Tags: java, android, event-handling

I am following the book Professional Android development by Reto Meier, and there is an example of a ToDo list to be done in order to practice.
The problem is that I do everything as the book says, but I cannot add any task when pushing the central KeyPad, as I get an exception and the program has to close.
I tried to debug in Eclipse, and apparently it cannot find the .class file (?)

Here is the code where all the bad things are happening, specially in the ***todoItems.add*** line:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                myEditText.setText("");
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi noloman, could you print your stacktrace please ?

Comment: Here it is:

`Class File Editor

Source not found
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file EditText.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below.`

By the way, it happens the same with View.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a shot - it uses View v that's passed in.
I assume that "todoItems" is properly instatiated

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        EditText edittxt = (EditText)v;

        todoItems.add(0, edittxt.getText().toString());

        return false;
    }
});
```